# create live stream with php

Tags: php, flash, audio, stream, broadcastreceiver

I want to create a live voice stream with many user support , think of 2000 users and each user stream to 500 user.

I can easily send live voice data with flash to server as binary , in server I do not know how can I share that binary live to users.

is there any way with PHP to do that ?

Comment: PHP has plenty of stream wrappers that should get you started http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php

Comment: @Mike B yes , I saw that link may months ago , but still can not find any useful info for streaming live data ( the data that is not fully ready , I mean audio )